# getting time value from bootstrap timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-timepicker

I am trying to get time value from bootstrap timepicker .
There are two forms within a table row.

**The first form is**

```
<tr>
    <form class="form-inline" id ="form1">
        <td>
            <div class="input-group  bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                <input id="" type="text" class="in_timepicker form-control input-small">            
            </div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div class="input-group  bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                <input id="" type="text" class="out_timepicker form-control input-small">                                
            </div>
        </td>       

        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-md btn-danger btnupdate" id="">Update</button>
        </td>
    </form>    
</tr>
```

**and the second form is**

```
 <tr>
     <form class="form-inline" id ="form2">                           
         <td>              
             <div class="input-group  bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                 <input id="" type="text" class="in_timepicker form-control input-small">                                
             </div>
         </td>

        <td>
            <div class="input-group  bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                <input id="" type="text" class="out_timepicker form-control input-small">                                
            </div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-md btn-danger btnupdate" id="">Update</button>
        </td>
    </form>    
</tr>
```

**The javascript code is**

```
 $('.in_timepicker').timepicker({

    minuteStep: 5,
    showInputs: false,
    disableFocus: true,
    defaultTime: false
});

$('.out_timepicker').timepicker({

    minuteStep: 5,
    showInputs: false,
    disableFocus: true,
    defaultTime: false
});


$("body").on("click", ".btnupdate", function () {        
    var intime = $(this).parent().siblings().children().children('.in_timepicker').val();
});
```

I am trying to get the intime value from both of  the forms separately and I have written what i have tried but I am still not successful .Please suggest ways to do it.

Comment: [The documentation](https://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/) covers this  (at the bottom of the page).

Comment: Note your selector isn't correct.

Comment: I have tried putting manual inputs and they work but timepicker is not getting instantiated i guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initialised the timepicker using the data attribute

```
 <input id="" type="text" class="out_timepicker form-control input-small" data-provide="timepicker"/>
```